# Use event to pass attribute from One component to Other

Tags: lightning, event

I have home page which has one button to create account. On click of save I want to hide my Home page component and open new component. 
My Account creation component is separate component which I have included on my home page. I am using  component to show hide home page but unable to get the boolean value on home page from Account creation page.

My code is:

## HomePageComponent:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:handler event="c:BP_NewAccountCreationEvent" action="{!c.getPopUpId}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="ShowNextPage" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
        {!v.body}
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.ShowNextPage}"
```

## AccountcreationJS

```
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {

    },
    saveAccount : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('IN SaveAccount')
        var action = component.get("c.createAccount");
        action.setParams({"newAcc" : component.get("v.newAccount")});
        action.setCallback(this,function(a){
            if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.ShowNextPage", "false");
                $A.createComponent(
                    "c:SampleComponent",
                    {

                    },
                    function(newCmp){
                        if (component.isValid()) {
                        component.set("v.body", newCmp);
                        }
                    }

                );

            } else if (a.getState() === "ERROR") {
                $A.log("Errors", a.getError());
                console.log('****Error****');
            }

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

I need ShowNextpage value from this controller to Home page component
.

Comment: It feels like there's some info missing, where is `saveAccount` called from? Maybe worth expanding your code to give the full picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller you setting a boolean value as **String**

<s>`component.set("v.ShowNextPage", "false");`</s>

You must set a **Boolean** value as

```
component.set("v.ShowNextPage", false);
```

Comment: @Tushar Mudgal I have edited the post